# Text won't absolutely position using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and HTML, and I am working on my final project for school.

I am trying to absolutely position some text "Welcome" to a div I've made. For some reason it won't position in relation to the div, I've looked it over 10 times and can't figure out why.

I want the "Welcome" text to sit at the bottom of the welcome div, however when I put `bottom:0px;` into the CSS, it doesn't position according to its parent container and instead goes 0px from the top of the whole screen.

Here's the code:

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

#welcome {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 420px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.w {
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 64px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <div id="welcome">
      <p class="w">Welcome</p>
    </div>
    <nav id="main nav"></nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because you have `position: relative` set on the `#header`. An absolute positioned element is always positioned to the nearest parent with a `position` set. Remove `position: relative` from the `header` and put it as a property of `wrapper`

Comment: or you can simply remove the `height` that is setted on `.w`

Comment: @CalvinNunes the OP is trying to have the `#welcome` element positioned relative to the `#wrapper`. How does removing `height` on the `p` address that?

Comment: OP didn't said relative to the `#wrapper` specifically (*"absolutely position some text "Welcome" to a div I've made..."* and *"it doesn't position according to it's parent container"* since parent is `#welcome` and text is `.w`) , but yeah, makes more sense, so removing height would not help here

Comment: @CalvinNunes you might be right. Upon rereading the question, I think I'm actually more confused, since the there is a `#welcome` element and "Welcome" text. We'll let the OP chime in here.

Comment: @CalvinNunes I updated my answer to reflect what I believe to be the correct answer based on your initial comment about height (with some additional updates for margin and line-height).

Comment: Based on informations we have until now from OP, your answer seems to be correct :)

Comment: Right on. Thanks for forcing me to reread that. HA!

Comment: @disinfor Thanks for your answer sir, so I should try adding position:absolute to the header, and then position:relative to the wrapper? What im trying to accomplish is:

`"Welcome" text (.w) positioned absolutely to the #Welcome div,

#Welcome div positioned absolutely to the #header div, 

#Header div positioned absolutely to the #wrapper div.`

Comment: @Bamblagram yeah, if that's what you want to do. Remember though, if you make the `#header` absolutely positioned, you will need to also give it a `width`. I updated my answer with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as CalvinNunes pointed out, is that you have a height set on `.w` div. And, `p` elements have `margin` and `line-height` values by default. You need to remove the margin and set the line-height to `1` or less (.5 makes the text touch the bottom of the green box).

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#welcome {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 420px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.w {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 64px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <header id="header">

    <div id="welcome">
      <p class="w">Welcome</p>
    </div>

    <nav id="main nav">
    </nav>

  </header>

</div>
<!-- End of wrapper-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close. Take the height away from the `.w` p tag and remove its margin as well:

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url(images/background.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#header {
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}

#welcome {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 420px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.w {
  /*height: 150px;*/
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 64px;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header id="header">
    <div id="welcome">
      <p class="w">Welcome</p>
    </div>
    <nav id="main nav"></nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this different from my posted answer?

Comment: @disinfor I didn't see your answer at the time I posted, but they are slightly different in that I focus on removing the margin and height style rules. It's good imo to have multiple answers that propose different solutions, even if the outcome is the same.

Comment: Mine also addresses the margin and line-height. I feel like the almost identical answers clutters SO.

Comment: @disinfor I don't address `line-height`. I address `height.`

Comment: yeah, so does mine. Again, you can keep the answer, it just seems like clutter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `absolute` on something, related dom element should be `relative, absolute` or `fixed`, depending on your needs.
Also check if your `absolute` element doesn't have some unneeded margins etc.

But in your usage case i don't think that there is absolute needed. you can use bigger paddings for parent element top. Also this can be achieved using `flex-end`, which will allow dynamic text input.

Comment: While this may answer the question, please put in an example with code.